# Error while deploying local python-based docker image on minikube kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to deploy a Python flask based application container on minikube locally in an attempt to learn kubernetes. But when I try the below command:

```sh
minikube kubectl -- create deployment hello-1 --image=mini-images
```

I get following error:

```
Failed to pull image "mini-images": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error 
response from daemon: pull access denied for mini-images, repository does not 
exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource 
is denied
```

I also tried to build the docker image directly following instructions for [this](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/) page, but the results are same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the image `mini-images` exist? `minikube` can't pull from your local docker environment; it needs to pull from an image registry of some sort (such as docker hub, or quay.io, or one you run yourself, etc).

Comment: Hi @larsks, you may be correct. The mini-images exist on my local docker environment. But I added the image to minikube docker cache, so it should load the image right?

Comment: Can you show in your question the process you followed between building the image and trying to use it in a deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the flag "--image-pull-policy" set to "never" when trying to use locally imported images:

```
minikube kubectl -- create deployment hello-1 --image=mini-images --image-pull-policy='never'
```